# How can I resolve a value error when trying to use Dask Describe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm working with a dataset which has is over 10GB large. I've managed to import it into a dask data frame using the code:

```
df = dd.read_csv('FileName.csv', dtype = dt, parse_dates = ['date'])
dt = ... # a list of columns names with their data type such as 'objects' and 'floats'.
```

I've been trying to run a `.describe()` function, but I keep getting the error:
ValueError: No non-trivial arrays found

Does anyone know how to get over this error?

Comment: Not sure why you get an error, but could you please try `df.describe(percentiles_method="tdigest", include=dt).compute()`. It should avoid the current error.

Comment: Also, `describe` works only on numeric and datetime columns.

Comment: @kate-melnykova thanks kate, do you know how I could exclude all the object related data types then?

Answer (score 1):

As @kate-melnykova mentioned in the comments describe only works with numeric and date time columns.